# Accessing NOAA web service with token

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, authentication, noaa

I recently requested a NOAA "token" to access their data. However, I keep receiving a "Token parameter is required" 404 error. Here is the URL I am using (note token is not the real one):

http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/locationcategories?Token=AbCdEfGhIjKl1234

I have been scouring google for about an hour now on just a simple example to see what I am doing wrong, but no luck. I'm hoping someone here can point out (and probably get a chuckle) what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Lowercase the string Token to token?

Comment: I tried that, and just did again to make sure, along with putting the token in single and double quotes. No luck.

Comment: Have you tried using an HTTPS connection (to secure the token)?

Comment: Is there something in the real token other than plain characters and numbers?

Comment: I tried the HTTPS connection idea which seemed plausible, but still no luck. The token consists only of upper and lower alpha chars. No numeric or special chars.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? I sent them an email today but haven't heard back yet. It looks like there's an option to use Python to send a token (I have not tried this), but not an option to send one directly as a URL in a web browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've figured out how to use their web services.  It looks like you have to send the token as a header instead of directly in the URL.  For example, you can download an add-on to your browser such as [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) that allows you to send `GET` and `POST` requests to web servers.  Then select the option to send a get request to the web server such as

> https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets

Then select the option to add a header.  For the header, enter `token` for the header and whatever the value of your token is for the value.  Select the **Send** button and you should get a result.  Hopefully this helps you or somebody else in the future.  Most programming languages such as python, ruby, Java, C#, etc. should have an option to send headers using a `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. I never did get a response from them, but this looks like it should work. I'll give it a try in the next couple of days.

Comment: looks like it's all `https` now - they implemented a 301 redirect for http requests :)

Answer (score 4):

[According to the documentation](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2), the token must go in the header, not the url:

An example using curl:

```
curl -H "token:<token>" url
```

An example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ url:<url>, data:{<data>}, headers:{ token:<token> } })
```

Example url:

```
http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-01
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone's trying to do this with PowerShell, here's an example:

```
$postparms =@{token="KkZJFCuahOZOxJFPaThisIsntAToken"}

Invoke-Restmethod -uri  http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets -headers $postparms
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python the following works:

```
import requests

my_headers = {'token' : 'xxxyyyzzz'}
response = requests.get('https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/datasets', headers=my_headers)
print(response.json())
```